# How to create only JSON API routes in rails in a most simplest way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

If I wish to create rails' routes with only API specific methods, i.e. `index`, `show`, `create`, `update` and `destroy` and DO NOT wish to create `new` and `edit`.

I can do it in the following way,

```
resources :aalu, except: [:new, :edit]
```

Or

```
resources :tamaatar, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
```

Do I have to keep on repeating this `except` or `only` on every resource declaration?

Is there any other way to achieve this by specifying it only once?

Comment: I particularly prefer the only way, but do not understand the difference.

Comment: @JavierValencia he is asking if there is a practical way of doing that to all his resources instead of doing that to each one =) I don't think there is a way of doing that without being hacky, each resource has it's restrictions.

Comment: @JavierValencia :only way is somewhat more explicit and hence enhances the clarity. Both of them are complimentary to each other and both of the above statements will work the same.

Comment: @SagarRanglani it is just a matter of opinion, I'd go with `except`

Comment: In a RestFul paradigm, resources do the same in two ways. Only change the perspective. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed, using [`with_options`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-with_options). Like this:

```
with_options except: [:new, :edit] do |opt|
  opt.resources :aalu
  opt.resources :tamaatar
end
```

Let me know if that helps!

**[edit]**

You don't even need to pass the argument to the block in this case. So you can use:

```
with_options except: [:new, :edit] do
  resources :aalu
  resources :tamaatar
end
```

Which I think is a bit neater.

Comment: This would work, it seems. Looks like a hack to me, nevertheless, Thank you for this!

Comment: It's a hack only in as much as it's a Rails extension on `Object`. Otherwise it's pretty useful!

Comment: Updated with a neater way of using `with_options`. If this does solve the issue for you, would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your included or excluded methods as:

```
included = {only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]}
excluded = {except: [:new, :edit]}
```

And then while defining the resource, you can use it like

```
resources :aalu, excluded
```

OR

```
resources :aalu, included
```

Comment: This is nothing different from what I am already doing, I'll have to anyways include `included` or `excluded` in the resource declaration.